# Lines after list items on Android browsers

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

I am having an issue with a drop down menu, where the menu that drops down has a buggy line after each list item. They don't seem to be from any styles that I've added, and I've tried removing every thing I could think of that might be causing it. The lines look solid in the picture below, but you can see that the first one is not as dark as the others. When zooming in on the list, some of the lines disapear completely, which makes me think that it is some kind of android bug?

[image: buggy lines]

The nav itself is structured like so:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="nav-button">
            <div id="nav-click" class="closed"><span>Menu</span></div>
            <ul class="sub-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The styles that are set up all work great apart from on android. The css for the `.sub-nav` is this. There are a lot more styles for the rest of the menu but I've left them out as It is only this sub list that is giving me issue.

```
.sub-nav li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the background from the `<a>` element and add the background to the `<ul>` element instead, there seems to be some strange sub-pixel gap between the `<a>` elements.